Can I use alpha channel from color attribute node?
When we're using color attribute we can store some data in it's channels. But what about alpha channel? Can I store data here? Won't it break other channels? Blender won't let me paint with alpha in vertex paint:

I've tried the solution of @Martynas Žiemys but it doesn't work for me for some reason:


Yes, Color Attributes can store Alpha:

And you are right that vertex painting for some reason does not allow painting with alpha values. You could attempt reporting this as a bug to the developers, maybe that's not intended functionality and just a mistake in the code.
You can also set color attributes with Set Attribute operator in edit mode. You can find it with search menu( F3 ) or in the Mesh menu:

It lets you use alpha:

To use Set Attribute operator, you need to have an attribute selected in the Properties Editor, Data tab:

That's because you can have multiple Color Attributes and you need to specify the one you want to set.

Thank you! I'm not so familiar with Blender for such reports. Do you know why I'm getting a message "Disabled. No active attribute"? I've selected color attribute in data properties.

I reported it. https://projects.blender.org/blender/blender/issues/131168 It's not really clear that it will be considered a bug, but let's see what the devs say.

Yes, you have to have an active attribute, it must be selected in the properties editor, I'll update the answer with a screenshot.

Sorry, missed the last sentence. If you have it selected, I have no idea, why it would give you that message. It works for me and I cannot replicate the issue.

Very strange. Can you, please, tell me where I can get more information about this operator? I can't understand how it works and documentation seems not so clear for me. There is no other mentions in internet as I can see. Or, maybe, I'm bad in searching (more likely).

Well, you just create an attribute and use the operator to set its value - that's pretty much it. Not sure why it doesn't work for you. Maybe try on the default scene. Jut add a color attribute, go to edit mode, select the geometry you want to set the attribute for and use the operator.

It works with a new file. Seems like my current file is broken. Thank you for your help.
